# Animate alpha value to let Bitmap disappear / fade out

Tags: android

I am rendering a `Bitmap` to a Android `Canvas`. The bitmap has an alpha Channel that is used to only display the parts that are visible and not occlude the background. I want to let the bitmap slowly disappear. My first idea was to kind of multiply it with a second alpha value that indicates how much of the image is still visible. Unfortunately it didn't work.
I tried something like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, alphaPaint);
```

where `alphaPaint` is a `Paint` object and I simply adjust its alpha value via

```
alphaPaint.setAlpha( .. );
```

But this won't do it. Do you have any other idea how to do it? I don't really want to change the alpha values of the bitmap itself since the bitmap is loaded once and used many times to save memory.

Comment: i dont know if its possible to do in a canvas but have you tried "animating" it with fade out?

Comment: I didn't try that yet because as far as I understand the animations are primarily for UIWidgets. I am in a situation where I have a fullscreen canvas (like in a game) and want to render a lot of these simple `Bitmap`s to this canvas. Should have mentioned that in the original text!